# reduce the total number of break and continue statements in this loop to use at most one

Tags: java

Buenas he creado un metodo el cual agrega las canciones seleccionadas para pertenecer a una playlist del usuario, esta  recibe como parametro la posicion de la cancion a guardar en la playlist, si ya esta agregada no permite agregarla nuevamente de lo contrario la agrega a otro arraylist llamado playlist

Pero me manda una advertencia en el for "reduce the total number of break and continue statements in this loop to use at most one ", que podria hacer para solucionarlo?

```
    public void createList(int number) {

        if (number > container.size()) {
            System.out.println("el numero de la cancion seleccionada no existe");

        } else {
            if (playArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                playArrayList.add(container.get(number - 1));
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < playArrayList.size();) {

                    if (playArrayList.get(i) == container.get(number - 1)) {
                        System.err.println("La cancion ya esta en la playlist");

                        break;
                    } else {
                        playArrayList.add(container.get(number - 1));
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: La advertencia bien puede ser de la configuración del editor que usas. Lo que sí es raro es que tienes un ir else que, en cualquier caso, vas entregar un break. Así pues, tienes un for que sólo corre una iteración...

Comment: Has probado a eliminar los 2 breaks que tienes y ponerlo fuera del if-else (dentro del for)?